# Powershell - возврат массива из функции

Tags: коллекции, powershell

День добрый.
Имеется функция, которая должна возвращать коллекцию объектов PSCustomObjects.
Однако при возврате, в начало коллекции добавляется какой то мусор.
Пример, создается коллекция с одним элементом, но при возврате в коллекции появляется мусор :

```
function GetArrayList()
{
    $Lists = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $Lists.Clear;
    $Lists.Add("hi");
    Write-Host $Lists;
    return $Lists;
}

$MyVar = GetArrayList;
Write-Host $MyVar;
```

Как мы видим, выводится содержимое коллекции до возврата из функции, и после. Результат :

```
hi
void Clear(), void IList.Clear() 0 hi
```

Откуда добавляются элементы void Clear(), void IList.Clear()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [известная особенность](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548723/clear-captured-output-return-value-in-a-powershell-function) PowerShell. Проблема в том что Write-Host в связки с функциями  .Net зачем то выводит интерфесы класса. Решение использовать комдлет  `Out-Null` для вызове функции чтоб скрыть "мусор". Если нужен результат функции не используй .Net arrayList используй Powershell Array